# PHP+JS: кавычки при переадресации

Tags: php, javascript, html

Немного запутанный код (смесь HTML, PHP и JS), но на самом деле всё просто: я хочу вывести через PHP такой HTML-код:

```
<button onClick="document.location="admin-edit-head.php?id=1""> 
---
<button>
```

Никак не могу понять: откуда берутся кавычки перед ID?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, я до этого ID посылал через переменную, но во время эксперимента выяснил, что и при непосредственном вводе то же самое.

```
echo  '<tr><td><button onClick="document.location="admin-edit-head.php?id='.$row["ID"].// и т. д.
```

---

**Обновление**

Ещё один интересный эффект: воткнул между кавычками "необязательную" для JS точку с запятой, но, как видите, эта точка с запятой теперь не между двумя кавычками (первая из которых закрывает адрес, вторая - `onClick=""`), а перед ними.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше при отлавнивании события onclick, вешать либо функцию либо сделать класс, при клике на котором эта функция вызовется. А так это бред,  да и так никто не пишет.
<button onClick="goToPage()"/></button>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В природе существуют не только двойные кавычки, но и одинарные.
Вот так

```
<button onClick="document.location='admin-edit-head.php?id=1'">
```

правильно.

А еще кавычки можно экранировать:

```
echo  '<tr><td><button onClick="document.location=\'admin-edit-head.php?id='.$row["ID"].'\'"';
```

Comment: Отлично, всё работает! Спасибо Вам за ответ! Но в чем была причина?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, нельзя внутри одних кавычек использовать эти же самые кавычки без экранирования.